# Bulking diet good enough?

Tags: bodybuilding, training, bulking

Just wanted to share my bulking diet, and see what I could improve to put on more weight.

I am currently a 25yo male, 1.72m tall and weight 68 kg.

I am trying to reach 72 kg which is the weight I will be happy about.

I train about 3-4 times a week and focus on low reps and heavy weights.

I have seen a lot of improvements in the last year because I started at about 56kg weight.

I feel like I have a reached a plateau with my weight ... this is why I am looking for some advices. I have also lost a bit of weight because developer a lot of lactose intolerance so can only handle isolate and not so much cheese.

**Wake up** - Isolate shake with lactose free full milk

**Breakfast**

- Oats , with lactose free greek yoghurt with spoon of honey
- Banana

**Morning snack** - Kit kat, fruits

**Lunch** - Always carbs and meat and veggies every day.

**Afternoon snack** - 2 sandwiches of peanut butter

**Dinner** - Mostly carbs , meat and veggies

**After dinner snack** - half a Cup of almonds

Comment: What's your daily protein intake like? Are you sleeping enough (at least 8 hour a night)? Are you drinking enough water (about 1ltr per 25kg of bodyweight, though it may vary). Those three factors are generally what's missing from people trying to put on weight. Track them for a month or two and see if you put on weight. If not, then track calories to make sure you're eating enough for a month or two.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @Dark Hippo in the comment section, many parameters can influence your weight gain.
But as far as nutrition goes, here is how to go about it:

Let's set optimal weight gain for a beginner/intermediate to be around 0.5% of your body weight a week.
Since you weigh 68 kg, that would mean 340 grams a week. Your goal being to be 72 kg, you can be there in 11-12 weeks. Let's round that up to 3 months.
At that rate, you'll mostly put on Fat free mass.

I would suggest weighing yourself every morning upon waking up. Track your progress. And count calories/macros.

If after a week you see yourself weighing more than what you're supposed to, back off a bit on the calories.
If instead you're not putting on enough weight, up your calories.
Repeat the process until the goal is achieved.